# Question regarding proof of Euclid's Division Lemma

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Below is a proof from David Burton introductory text on number theory that I was reading.
[image]

Here the proof assumes that the smallest integer in the set S is r and then proceeds to prove that $0<=r<b$. My idea is that using the two conditions, a=bq+r and $0<=r<b$, we have to lock down on the uniqueness of q and r. But in the proof, through the assumption that r is the least element of S, we show $0<=r<b$. Why can we make this assumption that r is the least element in the set S? Why should this hold true?

Comment: Which assumption?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos The assumption that r is the smallest element of S

Comment: Apparently you can assume that thanks to the Well Ordering Principle in Chapter 1.

Comment: @law-of-fives My question isn't whether there is a least element in an ordered set. Why wuestion is why r is that least element?

Comment: We don't assume that _r_ is the least element in **S**, we know **S** has a least element, and we're going to label it _r_.

Comment: @law-of-fives. Okay. I still have a problem with intuitively grasping this. Are we labeling r, and then working backward to prove that it is the r in the theorem.

Comment: That is correct @VishalSubramanyam.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @law-of-fives.

Answer (score 1):

Given $b \ne 0$, each pair of integers $(q,r)$ such that $0\le r \lt |b|$ is associated with a unique integer $b \cdot q+r $

I demonstrate below by construction for the case $b \gt 0$:

$\mathbb{Z}= \{\dots,b\cdot(-1)+0,~~ b\cdot(-1)+1,~\dots,~~b\cdot(-1)+(b-1),\\
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~b\cdot(~~~0)+0,~~ b\cdot(~~~0)+1,~\dots,~~b\cdot(~~~0)+(b-1),\\
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~b\cdot(~~~1)+0,~~ b\cdot(~~~1)+1,~\dots,~~b\cdot(~~~1)+(b-1),~...  \}$

I also demonstrate below by construction for the case $b \lt 0$:

$\mathbb{Z}= \{\dots,b\cdot(~~~1)+0,~~ b\cdot(~~~1)+1,~\dots,~~b\cdot(~~~1)+(b-1),\\
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~b\cdot(~~~0)+0,~~ b\cdot(~~~0)+1,~\dots,~~b\cdot(~~~0)+(b-1),\\
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~b\cdot(-1)+0,~~ b\cdot(-1)+1,~\dots,~~b\cdot(-1)+(b-1),~...  \}$

Notice, that in each case the map between $(q,r)$ and $b \cdot q+r $ is a bijection.

So, given $b \ne 0$, for any $a\in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists a unique pair $(q,r)$, such that $0\le r \lt |b|$ and $a=b \cdot q+r $

Comment: I wasn't sure where to put this proof, I'll move it if there's a better place.

Comment: I think you gain a constructive proof at the cost of having to define a map over all integers.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind the proof is that one subtracts $b$ from $a$ as many times as possible with the condition that what remains be non-negative, i.e. be in $\mathbf N$. As a fundamental property of the natural numbers is that any non-empty subset has a smallest element, you're sure such an $r$ exists.